# Need full rendered text of a given URL in javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a weird request. I am creating a platform where artists will create profile and show their stuff. Now most of the artists have their previous record or something inside some other website platforms like songkick or their own website. Now my client requirement is that the user will provide the url of their past data or something and the system will go through that website and get the content on the basis of some fields. E.g events data contain Event/Location/Date

I am using AWS Comprehend to analyze the data now the part where i am stuck in is getting the whole website data/text.

Lets say i have a url of https://www.something.com. I want to go to this website and get all the rendered text inside. Please suggest me if this is unethical or i need to do this with some other approach.

What i was trying to do right now and failing

```
fetch('https://www.somthing.com').then((response)=>console.log(response))
```

But this was giving me `fetch failed type error`

I know the first thought that will come in mind is to use the provided url platform API but most of the websites won't have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering the same thing then i used node js with `puppeteer` library and `request` library (deprecated)

**Puppeteer**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.kaiakater.com/shows");
const example = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const temp = Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"), (e1) => {});
```

**Request Library**

```
const requestFunction = () => {
 request("https://www.instagram.com/", function (error, response, body) {
 console.error("error:", error); 
 // Print the error if one occurred
 console.log("statusCode:", response && response.statusCode); 
 // Print the response 
 status code if a response was received
 console.log("body:", body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
};
```